# How to capture image of window that is partially cut off with scrollbars?

Tags: c#, winapi

Let's say I have this window open:

[image: The entire window shown]

And I then resize the window to look like this:

[image: Cutoff window]

Using Spy++ I can see that the window portion of the paint control is as follows:

[image: Spy++ with window handle]

Is it possible to capture the entire image (including cutoff part) so that I could get something like this returned?

[image: Captured image]

Comment: CTRL+A then CTRL+C just for the image part.

Comment: I need to do this in C#

Comment: is it only for paint? or for other applications as well?

Comment: @nevets for any window handle where it would render something

Comment: Have you tried using `WM_PRINT/WM_PRINTCLIENT`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are trying to do this by using GDI (accesing directly the HWND handler you are interested on to try get the entire image)

The only way to capture the entire image is by implementing code that scrolls the window and use different captures to compose the entire image.

The area identified by SPY++ is the window client visible drawing area and what is outside its bound is not redraw by GDI, what means that even if you can access the HWND and get a DC to make a direct copy, whatever is out of bounds will not be there.

Comment: Is there no way to essentially give that window enough real estate to draw itself in it's entirety, maybe by creating a different window and forcing it to render to this other window?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to resize the window, ask for a redraw, take the image snapshot and restore the height and width, however if it exceeds screen width and height you will have the same problem, what is out of screen is not render and all this process will be completely visible to user. If it is a MDI Child window you will need to resize the parent as well or you will have the same issue.